# how to auto adjust the length of submenu of primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

I create a dynamic menu with `<p:tieredMenu model="#{ServerGroupMgmtBean.model}" id="serverGroupMenu"/>`. If there are many menu items in the Submenu, some of the menus cannot display in one row. Is there any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change item's width by using style css directly, you can get component's style class by `Inspect element` function of browser, add this snippet code to your faceslet file(.xhtml,...):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-menu.ui-menu-parent.ui-menu-child{
     width: 120 % !important; // or anything you want
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Anyone figure out how to do this for only **one** sub-menu in a menu that contains multiple sub-menus?

Comment: @KevinRahe You can use `CSS :first-child Selector`.

Comment: @user2248738 Please mark as answer to close this question!