# Cannot scroll DIV for Primefaces' Tiered Menu

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces, scrollbar

How to do `auto scroll` for Primefaces `Tiered Menu`?

I would like to set div width `200px`. At that time, I cannot see the primefaces sub-menu.
I would like bring to front `sub-menu of tieredMenu`.

Code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fu="http://java.sun.com/jsf/fileUpload"
    template="/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("ul.ui-menu-list.ui-widget-content").css("position", "fixed");
        </script>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div style="overflow: auto;width:200px;height:200px;border:3px corsal solid;">
            <p:tieredMenu style="width:150px">  
                <p:submenu label="Ajax Menuitems">  
                    <p:menuitem value="Save"/>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Update"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax Menuitem">  
                    <p:menuitem value="Delete"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:separator />  
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
                    <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Prime"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces"/>  
                    </p:submenu>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:separator />  
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
                    <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Prime"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces"/>  
                    </p:submenu>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:separator />  
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
                    <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Prime"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces"/>  
                    </p:submenu>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:separator />  
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
                    <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Prime"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces"/>  
                    </p:submenu>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:separator />  
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
                    <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Prime"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces"/>  
                    </p:submenu>  
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile"/>  
                </p:submenu>  
            </p:tieredMenu>  
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("ul.ui-menu-list.ui-widget-content").css("position", "fixed");
            </script>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

[image]

Need your suggestions.

**Update**  I update the picture and code for more clear.

I would like to see `<p:submenu>` the top of `DIV`.

Comment: For setting up the width, something like this maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979300/how-to-auto-adjust-the-length-of-submenu-of-primefaces

Comment: @Andy, It is notwork for me. thz for your help

Comment: Do you want to bring sub-menu out of the scrollable DIV? right??

Comment: @KishorP Yes, I would like to do like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here use the following JQuery script, right after you closing the div tag:
[PUT the script after DIV tag]

> After Huge effort I finally came up with this script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var v = $("li.ui-widget.ui-menuitem.ui-corner-all.ui-menu-parent");
            $(v).bind("mouseover",function(event){
                var target = event.target;
                var mItem;

                if($(target).is("a")){
                    mItem = $(target).siblings("ul.ui-menu-list");
                }
                else if($(target).is("span")){
                    mItem = $(target).parent().siblings("ul.ui-menu-list"); 
                }

                if(mItem!=undefined){
                    var parnt = $(mItem).parent();
                    try{
                        var parpos = $(parnt).offset();
                        var x = parpos.left;
                        var y = parpos.top;
                        $(mItem).css('top',y);
                        $(mItem).css('position','fixed');

                    }catch(err){}
                }
            });
        </script>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, But, it is still cannot see the sub-menu. DIV cover the sub-menu like my picture.

Comment: I update as u suggest. `Position Fixed` is problem. Sub-menu display top of the browser. How can I click sub-menu. Plz, check my new uploaded image. Thanks for your supporting.

Comment: I'll fix it and let you know!!

Comment: see the edited answer. Please select it as correct answer(If it works for you)

Comment: @KishorP This is really nice.